# [.NET][C#] - Is possible to get a web with its links (CSS,JavaScript,Images, CSS-Images)?

Tags: .net, http, get, external

I am implementing a CMS, the case is that the "Web-Editable" is in a different domain thus, I would be able just get the page using HttpRequest in order to copy and show it in the CMS server to make it able to change it (DOM just visual purpose) and save the changes to the CSS and JavaScript folder on the "Web-Editable" using FTP.

I am not allow to download all the information included on the "Web-Editable" trough the FTP, and there are other dinamic images as well comming from a private database.

The question is, anyone knows how to make a httprequest "cascade" to get all the 1st level information you see when you visit a Web?

Thank you in advance,
Efrain

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML, then query the resulting document to get all JS, CSS and images (and other content, if you have it).

It exposes the dom similarly to how `XmlDocument` works.